# Foreach Loop Php Mysql retrieve

Tags: php

i want to retrieve mysql data using foreach loop,  as i had 10 employees records with expenses, i want to display each employee name and his expenses with a table in a loop. please suggest me how to call this function using foreach

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees where dt >= '$from' AND dt <= '$to' ORDER by empname ASC");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{

$ta = $result["ta"];
$da = $result["da"];
$petrol = $result["petrol"];
}
```

I need report like this.

```
Empname:

Record1 Record2
-----------------
Empname:

Record1 Record2
---------------
```

Please help.

Comment: Btw, you are messing `$data` with `$result`

Comment: Please use mysqli or PDO, as `mysql_*` is officially deprecated and should not be used anymore. Also, small "i" should not be used in questions neither :-)

Comment: Please provide more details like what is Record1, Record2, $ta, $da, $petrol and how you are retrieving the value of Empname, Record1, Record2?

Comment: @BolemVeeru why do you want to use a foreach if you can do it all with your while ?

Comment: [Don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use SO](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

---

Since you're using `mysql_*`, I hope you're using `mysql_real_escape_string` on your `$to` and `$from` variables if they are coming from user input.

I am still not sure why you want to use a `foreach` but what you want to do, can be done with `while` which is also a loop:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees where dt >= '$from' AND dt <= '$to' ORDER by empname ASC");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{
    $rows[] = $result;
}

print_r($rows);
```

Here is a working example using MySQLi:

```
<?php
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];

if (is_null($from) || is_null($to))
    die('You must fill the from and to fields...');

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test_database');
if($db->connect_error)
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

if (!$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT empname, ta, da, petrol FROM employees WHERE dt >= ? AND dt <= ?"))
    die('Prepare Error: ' . $db->error);

if (!$stmt->bind_param('ss', $from, $to))
    die('Bind Parameters Error ' . $stmt->error);

if (!$stmt->execute())
    die('Select Query Error ' . $stmt->error);

$stmt->bind_result($empname, $ta, $da, $petrol);
$rows = array();
while($stmt->fetch())
{
    $rows[$empname][] = array('ta' => $ta, 'da' => $da, 'petrol' => $petrol);
}
$stmt->close();
$db->close();

foreach ($rows as $empname=>$data)
{
    echo $empname . ':<br /><br />';
    foreach ($data as $result)
    {
        echo $result['ta'] . ' ' . $result['da'] . '<br />';
        echo '-----------------<br />';
        $petrol = $result['petrol'];
    }
    echo '==========================<br />';
}
```

Output:

```
Jorge:<br /><br />
12 3<br />
-----------------
1 4<br />
-----------------
2 6<br />
-----------------
3 1<br />
-----------------
33 11<br />
-----------------
==========================<br />
John:<br /><br />
4 3<br />
-----------------
5 6<br />
-----------------
6 8<br />
-----------------
7 9<br />
-----------------
8 10<br />
-----------------
==========================<br />
```

Comment: Sorry Guys for late. @prix i can retrieve data using while but i need records by employee name and important thing is i need all records with that employee name should display in table. example i have 10 records with two user names. they are not in sequence order in mysql but i need first user name should display 5 records of his.

Comment: @BolemVeeru I see, that was some very important information missed on the main question, I will update my answer and let u know in a few.

Comment: Yes, But it is not working tried. it is printing all records but i need all records in row by user name.

Comment: @BolemVeeru `$rows[$data['empname']][] = $result;` see if this is what u want.